# ZZ plant help please

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, zzplant

I'm just getting started with indoor plants and heard the ZZ plant was easy and impossible to kill.

I thought it was doing alright, not overwatering etc. But there are some white spots on the leaves. They've been there since I bought it, and the shopkeeper said they were nothing to worry about.

Are they anything to be concerned about? How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is there  anything under the leaves such as insects - have a look  with a magnifying glass, just in case - there are residue marks from fluids, but they're nothing worry about, not sure what the other whitened areas are though, your photo is somewhat out of focus and does not magnify well

Answer (score 2):

The white spots are a mixture of pesticide residue and hard water stains from overhead watering in the grower's greenhouse.

Wiping the leaves with a damp cloth is usually sufficient to remove the residue.